# Вывести всю информацию из xml-файл

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Всем привет!
надеюсь на вашу помощь :)

Есть xml-файл на 5000 строк, например такого вида:

```
<slugs>
            <slug>
                <storyId>591921840</storyId>
                <storyTitle>JN_MDG_SHAPKA</storyTitle>
                <storyStatus>7105</storyStatus>
                <storyDur>00:00:11:24</storyDur>
                <storyCreated>03/60/2023 16:00:10</storyCreated>
                <storyCreatedBy>Server</storyCreatedBy>
                <storyModified>03/60/2023 16:00:10</storyModified>
                <storyModifiedBy>Server</storyModifiedBy>
                <storyCustom name="col1" label="NLE"></storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col2" label="Test1"></storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col3" label="Test2 ">false</storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col4" label="Test3 ">false</storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col5" label="Test4"></storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col6" label="Test5"></storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col7" label="taskNumbers">12</storyCustom>
                <slugId>591912579</slugId>
                <script>
                    <main>
                        <body>
                            <element>
                                <elementId>2</elementId>
                                <elementType>Good</elementType>
                                <elementDur>00:00:11:24</elementDur>
                                <clip>
                                    <clipName>JN_MDG_SHAPKA</clipName>
                                    <clipMosId>stratus</clipMosId>
                                    <clipObjId>00008RIO</clipObjId>
                                    <clipFilePath></clipFilePath>
                                    <clipIn></clipIn>
                                    <clipOut></clipOut>
                                </clip>
                                <text></text>
                                <commands/>
                            </element>
                        </body>
                    </main>
                </script>
</slug>
<slugs>
            <slug>
                <storyId>591951842</storyId>
                <storyTitle>JN_MDG_SHAPKA2</storyTitle>
                <storyStatus>7105</storyStatus>
                <storyDur>00:00:11:24</storyDur>
                <storyCreated>03/60/2023 16:00:10</storyCreated>
                <storyCreatedBy>Server</storyCreatedBy>
                <storyModified>03/60/2023 16:00:10</storyModified>
                <storyModifiedBy>Server</storyModifiedBy>
                <storyCustom name="col1" label="NLE"></storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col2" label="Test1"></storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col3" label="Test2 ">false</storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col4" label="Test3 ">false</storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col5" label="Test4"></storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col6" label="Test5"></storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col7" label="taskNumbers">84623</storyCustom>
                <slugId>591912579</slugId>
                <script>
                    <main>
                        <body>
                            <element>
                                <elementId>2</elementId>
                                <elementType>Good</elementType>
                                <elementDur>00:00:11:24</elementDur>
                                <clip>
                                    <clipName>JN_MDG_SHAPKA2</clipName>
                                    <clipMosId>stratus</clipMosId>
                                    <clipObjId>00008RIO</clipObjId>
                                    <clipFilePath></clipFilePath>
                                    <clipIn></clipIn>
                                    <clipOut></clipOut>
                                </clip>
                                <text></text>
                                <commands/>
                            </element>
                        </body>
                    </main>
                </script>
</slug>
<slugs>
            <slug>
                <storyId>591921840</storyId>
                <storyTitle>JN_MDG_SHAPKA343</storyTitle>
                <storyStatus>7105</storyStatus>
                <storyDur>00:00:11:24</storyDur>
                <storyCreated>03/60/2023 16:00:10</storyCreated>
                <storyCreatedBy>Server</storyCreatedBy>
                <storyModified>03/60/2023 16:00:10</storyModified>
                <storyModifiedBy>Server</storyModifiedBy>
                <storyCustom name="col1" label="NLE"></storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col2" label="Test1"></storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col3" label="Test2 ">false</storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col4" label="Test3 ">false</storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col5" label="Test4"></storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col6" label="Test5"></storyCustom>
                <storyCustom name="col7" label="taskNumbers"></storyCustom>
                <slugId>591912579</slugId>
                <script>
                    <main>
                        <body>
                            <element>
                                <elementId>2</elementId>
                                <elementType>Good</elementType>
                                <elementDur>00:00:11:24</elementDur>
                                <clip>
                                    <clipName>JN_MDG_SHAPKA343</clipName>
                                    <clipMosId>stratus</clipMosId>
                                    <clipObjId>00008RIO</clipObjId>
                                    <clipFilePath></clipFilePath>
                                    <clipIn></clipIn>
                                    <clipOut></clipOut>
                                </clip>
                                <text></text>
                                <commands/>
                            </element>
                        </body>
                    </main>
                </script>
</slug>
```

С помощью гугл-таблицы необходимо вывести на отдельный лист вывести всю информацию только из тех блоков, где встречается номер в `taskNumbers`, между тегами `storyCustom name="col7" label="taskNumbers` и `storyCustom`.

То есть, например, если вставить в таблицу данные, которые я написал выше, ответ должен быть следующий:

```
Найдено количество taskNumbers: 2 шт. (12, 84623)
taskNumbers: 12
storyId: 591921840
storyTitle: JN_MDG_SHAPKA
storyStatus: 7105
storyDur: 00:00:11:24
storyCreated: 03/60/2023 16:00:10
storyCreatedBy: Server
storyModified: 03/60/2023 16:00:10
storyModifiedBy: Server
NLE:
Test1:
Test2:
Test3:
Test4:
Test5:
slugId: 591912579
```

```
taskNumbers: 84623
storyId: 591951842
storyTitle: JN_MDG_SHAPKA2
storyStatus: 7105
storyDur: 00:00:11:24
storyCreated: 03/60/2023 16:00:10
storyCreatedBy: Server
storyModified: 03/60/2023 16:00:10
storyModifiedBy: Server
NLE:
Test1:
Test2:
Test3:
Test4:
Test5:
slugId: 591912579
```

что мне удалось сделать:

```js
function XML() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxx');
  const list_xml = ss.getSheetByName('xml');
  const data = list_xml.getDataRange().getValues();
  const taskNumbers = [];
  let count = 0;

  list_xml.getRange('E2:Q4').clearContent();

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const row = data[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
      const cell = row[j];
      if (cell.indexOf('<storyCustom') !== -1 && cell.indexOf('name="col7"') !== -1) {
        const labelStartIndex = cell.indexOf('label="taskNumbers"');
        if (labelStartIndex !== -1) {
          const contentStartIndex = cell.indexOf('>', labelStartIndex) + 1;
          const contentEndIndex = cell.indexOf('</storyCustom>', contentStartIndex);
          const taskNumber = cell.substring(contentStartIndex, contentEndIndex).trim();
          if (taskNumber !== '') {
            taskNumbers.push(taskNumber);
            count++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (count > 0) {
    const result = `найдено количество taskNumbers: ${count} шт. (${taskNumbers.join(', ')})`;
    Logger.log(result);
    list_xml.getRange('E2:Q4').setValue(result);
  } else {
    Logger.log('taskNumbers не найдено.');
    list_xml.getRange('E2:Q4').setValue('taskNumbers не найдено.');
  }
}
```

1. открываем электронную таблицу Google Sheets по ее идентификатору;
2. получает список значений (данных) со страницы "xml";
3. проходим по каждому элементу из списка данных и ищем строки со специфическим текстом (содержащим `<storyCustom` и `name="col7"`);
4. если найдена строка с таким текстом, она ищет подстроку с меткой `label="taskNumbers"` и получает номер задания, который находится между тегами `<storyCustom>` и `</storyCustom>`;
5. если номер задания не пуст, она добавляет его в список номеров задач;
6. после прохождения всех элементов, функция проверяет, был ли найден хотя бы один номер задания;
7. если номера задач были найдены, функция устанавливает значение в ячейке "E3" с результатом, содержащим количество найденных редакционных задач и их номера;
8. если номера задач не были найдены, функция устанавливает значение в ячейке "E3" со строкой, сообщающей, что редакционные задачи не найдены;

в каком направлении дальше двигаться? :)

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы делаете в корне не правильно, т.к. xml является файлом разметки, которая изначально подчиняется каким-то правилам. Для каждого языка есть т.н. "парсеры", которые преобразуют текст в структуру языка. Это важно понять. Прочтите еще раз этот абзац.

В Apps Script используется встроенный метод `parse()` класса `XmlService`. Его можно без труда найти в справке.

Пример на ваших данных

```js
function extractDataXML() {
  const xml = getDataAsXMLString_();
  const doc = XmlService.parse(xml);
  const slugs = doc.getRootElement();

  const slugsList = slugs.getChildren('slug');
  const values = slugsList.map((slug) => {
    const storyId = slug.getChild('storyId').getText();
    const storyStatus = slug.getChild('storyStatus').getValue();
    const storyTitle = slug.getChild('storyTitle').getValue();
    return [storyId, storyTitle, storyStatus];
  });
  if (values.length) {
    console.log(values);
    values.unshift(['storyId', 'storyStatus', 'storyTitle']);
    const book = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sheet = book.getSheetByName('Работа с XML') || book.insertSheet('Работа с XML');
    sheet.clearContents().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
}
```

Результат работы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример в Таблице https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MqeW7LkEUcsDH8lUksXBLHWmSeu8up2Jr_3ujVwE4SE/edit#gid=941647450&range=D23

Comment: спасибо, я почитаю об этом подробнее.
подскажите, при запуске вашего кода выдает ошибку

ReferenceError: getDataAsXMLString_ is not defined

я так понимаю, нет ссылки на то, откуда брать данные? данные у меня находятся в соседнем листе в этой гугл таблице

Comment: @Dima, вероятно, функции `getDataAsXMLString_()` нет в вашем коде. В моем есть, я поэтому пример и привел.

Comment: скопировал просто ваш код :)

Comment: @Dima, см. пример.

Comment: пример увидел, спасибо. но не понимаю, откуда берете данные. Как минимум, даже не вижу ссылку на файл xml

Comment: @Dima, я вам не верю. Я открываю пример и передо мной `getDataAsXMLString_()` который возвращает строку.